# Spring Tool Suite keeps adding unwanted VM arguments

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I have a Pivotal tc Server 3.1 server configured in STS for debugging. The first problem I had was that it wasn't showing me JSP errors in the console when debugging. I discovered that removing the following VM arguments from my run/debug VM arguments resolved the problem...

-Djava.util.logging.manager=com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.logging.TcServerLogManager 
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.1.RELEASE/my-server/conf/logging.properties

But once I stop the server and re-run it again, those arguments magically get put back in there!  Anybody know a way to stop this from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Run -> Run Configurations... find a launch config corresponding to your server under Pivotal tc Server category. Click on it and then in the launch config editor pane click on Arguments tab, find VM Arguments text box and edit your VM arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately that's exactly where the problem is. Those are the arguments I'm talking about.  I remove those arguments I specified above, click Apply, then Run and all is good.... UNTIL I stop the server and run again.  After that, those dang arguments appear back in that panel again!

Comment: Something is re-adding them without my permission... frustrating.

Comment: Raise a JIRA in STS against SERVER component: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS Will probably make it a preference setting

Comment: as a workaround, you could duplicate the launch config and remove the arguments in the copied version (as use that). It is not very comfortable (so Alex comment from above still applies, please file an improvement request), since you would have to start the server using this copied launch config (instead of the "run" button in the servers view), but maybe the workaround still helps you at least a bit.